# How to curl down image and CSS as well

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Here is my code, which although worked very well, but cannot display image and let css effect, so how to make css effect and display images?

```
$cookie_file = tempnam('./temp','cookie');
$login_url = 'http://www.ifreewind.net/iFreeWind.aspx';
$post_fields = '__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE3NjQ3MDc3NDQPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAQUSUmVtZW1iZXJNZUNoZWNrQm94r57YdIUtbSps%2FGLW1PUtjxcILdE%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQLKivfjBgLw2N3fDgLC9%2FChAwLxuKbKAgL%2BjNCfDwU6DJjH4Q2acTlGVXmDrSv2Nn4G&UserNameTextBox=myaccount%40gmail.com&PasswordTextBox=mypass&LoginButton=%E7%99%BB%E9%99%86';

$ch = curl_init($login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$url = 'http://www.ifreewind.net/Users/Index.aspx';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

//preg_match("",$contents,$arr);
//echo $arr[1];

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 

"make css effect and display images"?

Do you want to dump a webpage, along with all of its elements?

Comment: yes, just like dump a webpage, but I don't want to just use `file_get_contents()` or `fopen()`, because the page require login. I need to curl down and grab only whatever I want, such as images, text and so on, which only can be see after login.

Comment: Use php to parse the html you get, then get all the images, css and js required, overwrite the `href` and `src` in the html.

Comment: Thank you , that's what I figured out. Could you just reply it as so I can choose as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by

> make css effect and display images

Do you want to dump a webpage, along with all of its elements?

If so, you can use try the following steps:

1. Use php to parse the html, then get the urls of all the images, css and js required.
2. Dump all the elements needed to your local server.
3. Overwrite the `href`s and `src`s in the html, point them to your local dump.